# If $X$ is finite and $R$ is a complete and reflexive binary relation on $X$, then $M(R, S) \neq \emptyset$ on any $S \subset X$ iff $R$ is acyclic.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Could you help me to verify my proof and my writing?

**Definition 1:** A binary relation $R$ on $X$ is complete if, for all $x, y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$,$xRy$ or $yRx$ or both and reflexive if, for all $x \in X$, $xRx$.

**Definition 1.01:** If we have $x \lnot R y$ and $y R x$, we have a binary relation $P$ on $X$ such that $yPx$.

**Definition 2:** For a weak preference relation $R$ on a choice set $X$, the maximal set $M(R, X) \subset X$ is defined as $M(R,X) = \{ x \in X | x R y \forall y \in X\}$.

**Definition 3:** A binary relation $R$ is acyclic if on any finite set $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\} \in X$, $x_i P x_{i+1}$ for all $i < n$ implies $x_1Rx_n$ and $x_n \lnot Px_1$.

**Proposition**. If $X$ is finite and $R$ is a complete and reflexive binary relation on $X$, then $M(R, S) \neq \emptyset$ on any $S \subset X$ ( except $S = \emptyset$ ) iff $R$ is acyclic.

**Proof:** We know that the binary relation $R$ on $S$ is complete and reflexive because it is complete and reflexive on $X$, and $S$ is subset of $X$.

$\Rightarrow$

Assume $M(R,S)$ is not empty. Define a finite set $S \subset X$ such that $S = \{s_1, s_2, ..., s_n\}$ . Suppose $s_1 P s_2 P ... P s_n$. Then for all $s \in S$ such that $s \neq s_1$, there exists $r \in S$ such that $r P s$. As $M(R,S)$ is not empty, $M(R,S)$ can only be $\{s_1\}$, then $s_n \lnot P s_1$ and $s_1 R s_n$. The relation is acyclic.

$\Leftarrow$

Suppose $R$ is acyclic on $S$, then $s_1 P s_2 P ... P s_n$  implies $s_1 R s_n$. Extending the definition for any $j$ such that $n \geq j \geq 2$ we conclude that $s_1 R s_j$ and $s_j \lnot P s_1$ . Then M(R,S) is not empty.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

You contradict yourself in definition 3 with:

A binary relation R is acyclic if on any finite set ${x_1 ,x_2 ,...,x_n }∈X , x_i Px_i+1  \quad\forall i<n \quad \text{implies} \quad x_1 Rx_n \quad \text{and}\quad  x_n ¬Px_1$.

But in your proof you use $s_1$ and $1\not \lt1$.

The rest looks okay, you could define $s_1Ps_2..Ps_n$ better - which way round is this supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you...

Comment: which bit - you claim for all i<n, but you then claim M must be s_1, and claim this makes s_1 acyclic to s_n, which is different than your claim that i<n.

Comment: I'm not getting your point. Why are they different?

Comment: Because you have $s_1Ps_1$ which isn't covered by your proof.

Comment: Which part? $s_1 P s_1$ because $R$ is reflexive and by definition of $P$, we can never have $x P x$ for any  x, in the same time.

I've just seen a typo in my second proof.

Comment: Your proof actually seems to ignore R is reflexive as currently P is undefined with {x,x}, so you need to define xPx. But how can an element be acyclic to itself. (another point which is probably covered elsewhere, what's a 'choice set').

Comment: That looks better. Shouldn't $S \subseteq X$

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $P$ could be clarified as $xPy$ if $xRy $ and not $yRx$

You make no assumption of transitivity in the definition of $R$ or $P$, so the conclusion that $M(R,S) = s_1$ doesn't follow immediately, and could use some expansion.

In your final section you seem to argue in the wrong order: you have $s_1Rs$, $\forall s$ implies $s_1Rs_i$ $\forall i$ when your argument is the other way round.

But these are issues of clarity not of thought.

Comment: I'm not assuming transitivy, just that R is acyclic.